# dsquery remote AD server

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

Im attempting to do a dsquery on a remoter AD server that I have access to through my network(No UN and PASS required).

`dsquery server -s <server name>` is supposed to connect me to a server while
`dsquery user -name <username>` is supposed to search for a certain user.

I attempted to combine the two with "&&" but it just get a list of LDAP object.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible ? 
I've searched but do not seem to find anything on the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dsquery server` is for finding server instances, not connecting to a server - there's no session or setting persistence from one run of `dsquery` to another.

To do this query against a specific server, this would be the syntax:

```
dsquery user -name <username> -s <servername>
```

However, this is a query against the user's name, not their account name (unsure of whether it's looking at the `displayName`, `cn`, or some other attribute) - to query against a user's account name this would be the query to use:

```
dsquery user -samid <username> -s <servername>
```

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct as I do not get an error but on the other hand I do not get a result. I found a user in AD UI but when I do the search in CMD a get no result. So I'm assuming there is an issue on my end rather than the syntax/dsquery...

Comment: Are you looking for the user's full name or the account name?  `-name` looks at the full name, `-samid username` might be what you need instead.

Comment: when I user the same search format for my local domain  I get a result. so dsquery user -name <username> -s <local servername> server returns a result while dsquery user -name <username> -s <remote servername> does not

Comment: Are both of those systems domain controllers?  On the same domain?

Comment: your first comment fixed my issue. MUCH appreciated !. How do I make your comment as the answer ? Can you paste what you explained in the answer box so I can mark it as the answer or do I mark the original ?  Im guessing the original is valid

Comment: Great!  I'll edit the answer with the additional information.

Comment: Sounds good ! I marked the answer as correct and thanks again